# Не понятна работа функции фильтрации в TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Читаю книгу Pro Angular. Не понимаю в чем смысл записи в функции .filter(...)

```
get categories(): string[] {
return this.model.getProducts()
.map(p => p.category)
.filter((category, index, array) => array.indexOf(category) == index);}
```

Знаю, что это функция фильтрации в массиве, но зачем проверять заведомо известный индекс элемента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае это пример получения уникальных значений в массиве:

[`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) проверяет элементы с начала массива, и если в массиве будет несколько одинаковых элементов - то в этом случае индекс совпадет только для первого вхождения:

```js
var a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4];

console.log(a.filter((cur, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(cur) === i));
```

---

Однако, это может не сработать с объектами, так как в этом случае два объекта будут считаться разными, не смотря на то, что имеют одинаковые значения в полях

```js
var a = [{
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 1
}];
console.log(a.filter((cur, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(cur) === i))
```

В этом случае лучше использовать метод `findIndex`

```js
var a = [{
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 1
}];
console.log(a.filter((cur, i, arr) => arr.findIndex(c => c.a === cur.a) === i))
```